# Var_dump in php is not printing the total content just showing

Tags: php

My requirement is to read the content of a php file and show the content in front end.
    For this I have used

```
$section = file_get_contents('test.php');
var_dump($section);
?>
```

But it is printing the values, and after some charater, it is just printing ... not the complete content. I have tried to print through echo and print_r method but in no case i got the full content.

My app.php is something like this :

```
<?php
$data =  array(
        array('id' => 1, 'first' => "abc", 'last' => 'def', 'email' => 'abc@def.com'),
        array('id' => 2, 'first' => "ghi", 'last' => 'jkl', 'email' => 'abc@def.com'),
        array('id' => 3, 'first' => "mno", 'last' => 'pqr', 'email' => 'abc@def.com'),
        array('id' => 4, 'first' => "stu", 'last' => 'vwx', 'email' => 'abc@def.com'),
        array('id' => 5, 'first' => "Y", 'last' => 'Z', 'email' => 'abc@def.com'),
       );
    echo json_encode(array(
            'success'   => true,
            'message'   => 'loading data',
            'data'      => $data
        ));
?>
```

Comment: Use `var_export()` or `print_r()` instead; `var_dump()` will truncate data by design (to avoid large output)

Answer (score 4):

You need to [escape](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) characters like `<` and `>` to `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

```
var_dump(htmlentities($section));
```

Or:

```
echo htmlentities($section);
```

If you do a 'view source' in your browser you'll see that the rest is actually there but your browser is trying to interpret the text as HTML.

Also note that `file_get_contents` doesn't `execute` the PHP (test.php in your example); it just reads the file as if it's a text-file. You might want to have a look at [include](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), [include_once](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php), [require](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) or [require_once](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) if you want the code in the file to actually be executed.

Answer (score 3):

you try to echo code it will try to parse it, so pass it through htmlspecialchars($source) and it should work.

Something like this:

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
echo htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents('test.php'));
echo "</pre>";
```

?>

Answer (score 2):

Hey I know its bit late but i hope someone can get help from here...

These are configurable variables in php.ini:

Try to find `; XDEBUG Extension`

```
zend_extension = "your path to php/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.4-vc9-x86_64.dll"

[xdebug]
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 10
```

Of course, these may also be set at runtime via `ini_set()`, useful if you don't want to modify php.ini and restart your web server but need to quickly inspect something more deeply.

```
ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_depth', 10);
```

Hope this help someone!